# Google Chrome 35 - Installing older versions of browsers

Tags: google-chrome

I have some software that only works with Google chrome 35 and 37.

I want set one of my users up with this software - but I don't know where to find the download for 35 or 37.

Any ideas on a good resource for old browser's?

Comment: I am also interested in Chrome 37.

Answer (score 1):

There are third-party sites that provide old versions of Google Chrome such as [OldVersion.com](http://www.oldversion.com/windows/google-chrome/) and [OldApps](http://www.oldapps.com/google_chrome.php).

Comment: OldApps only has dev and beta versions since v30 and OldVersion has v22 as the latest vrelease version.

Comment: @DavidPostill I see 34.0.1847.116 (not dev or beta) at OldApps...

Comment: Ah. Missed that. But in any case no 35 or 37 which is what the OP wants ...